# How to exit remote-desktop session without logging off mouse free?

Tags: remote-desktop

I am using a Windows 8.1 machine to remote-access a Windows 7 machine through Remote Desktop Connection. Currently, the only way I find to exit the RDP session is to hover the mouse cursor to the top, wait for the following dropdown bar to appear and click the "close" button.

[image: "exit bar" that may stop a remote desktop session.]

Is there another way to existing an RDP session while in a RDP session? Say, through command line? Or, keyboard shortcuts? On my local machine, I notice that I can as well kill the mstsc.exe session to exit it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start -> Windows Security -> Disconnect

Also, `tsdiscon` from command prompt or run dialog.

Comment: Thanks! I end up with creating a bat file with only `tsdiscon` in it and mapped such bat file to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Fantastic tip, I use it through [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), bound to Ctrl+F12. Mouse no more!